# Github says that I have changes in my forked repo, but those changes are already merged in the main repo

Tags: git, github

I did the following:

- Forked a repo in github
- Commited a change on my forked repo
- Created a PR in order to merge changes to the original repo
- PR got merged

After doing this, the changes were merged in the original repo, and I got last changes done on the upstream repo using the Github tool for comparing repos. After doing this, if I click on "Compare" button, it shows my change as a difference. Why this is happening? If the same change is in both repos, they should be equal in content, right?

I deleted my forked repo and forked the original repo again, but that wasn't cool, I would like to know what is really happening :)

Comment: You probably didn’t need to delete your fork. Did you ever update your local repo after the original repo merged the PR?

Comment: I synced my github repo with a lot of changes from the repo that was forked in the first place. Directly from github. But the problem remains, that's why I ended up deleting it and forking again.

Comment: You say clicked “compare”. What branches are you comparing?

Comment: I compared master branches on both repos.

Comment: It’s likely that your master branch wasn’t updated with the upstream repo.

Comment: It was, I updated my question. I got all the changes from the upstream repo through a PR using the online tool from Github, that let us create a PR with the changes and merge it.